# Arduino libraries problem on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: libraries, 22.04, arduino

I want help because I have a problem with the arduino IDE. I wanted to use a RFID module so I installed the libraries but when I click on "verify", the Arduino's terminal, I've got that:

```
Warning: platform.txt from the 'Arduino AVR Boards' core contains compiler.path={runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path}/bin/ exceeded, automatically converted to compiler.path=/usr/bin/. It is advisable to upgrade this heart.
/media/netherr591/elegoo/Français/code/Lesson 21 RC522 RFID Module/MF-RC522_RFID/MF-RC522_RFID.ino:29:17: fatal error: SPI. h: No file or folder of this type
compilation completed.
exit status 1
Build error for Arduino Mega or Mega 2560 board
```

Comment: With other codes, I have no problems if it doesn't require libraries

Comment: could you please edit the question so that it includes the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a simple program to measure weights through HX711 library. I suggest, in case my solution do not suit you, to enable "detailed output" option checked out" from file/preferences. So you copy to the clipboard the whole instructions for your script.

In my case, I found it by trying to compile a program from the command line. First

gcc-avr nor avr-libc were not on arduino's dependencies. So after installing them, I got  it running.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks, it helped me much. Arduino works again !